# Submission of form in mysql database using Flask

Tags: python, mysql, flask

main.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

# configure the SQLite database, relative to the app instance folder
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = 'mysql://root:@localhost/abhiblog'


# create the extension
db = SQLAlchemy()


class Contactsdata(db.Model):
    sno = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    msg = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)


@app.route('/contact', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def contact():
    if (request.method == 'POST'):
        # Add a entry to the database
        name = request.form.get('name')
        email = request.form.get('email')
        msg = request.form.get('msg')
        entry = Contactsdata(name=name, email=email, msg=msg)
        db.session.add(entry)
        db.session.commit()
    return render_template('contact.html', params=params)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

contact.html

```
<main class="mb-4">
    <div class="container px-4 px-lg-5">
        <div class="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-7">
                <p>Want to get in touch? Fill out the form below to send me a message and I will get back to you as soon
                    as possible!</p>
                <div class="my-5">
                    <form id="contactForm" method="POST" action="/contact">
                        <div class="form-floating">
                            <input class="form-control" id="name" type="text" name="name" required
                                placeholder="Enter your name...">
                            <label for="name">Name</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-floating">
                            <input class="form-control" id="email" type="email" required name="email"
                                placeholder="Enter your email...">
                            <label for="email">Email address</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-floating">
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="message" required name="msg"
                                placeholder="Enter your message here..." style="height: 12rem"></textarea>
                            <label for="message">Message</label>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <button class="btn btn-primary text-uppercase" id="submitButton" type="submit">Send</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Phpmyadmin dashboard table
[image]

I am trying to insert data to my database using flask and mysql but I am stuck at this point where I am getting a SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS error, please help me out to fix it, Thank you in advanced!!!

SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS Error
[image]

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you tried to identify and then fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried turning track modifications to False after your app.config for database URI?

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I tried but unfortunately, it's not working. This time it throws AssertionError